# A limit to absorption by black holes?

Tags: gravity, black-holes

We know that a black hole draws everything nearby into it but is there a limit to which black holes can consume matter into it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mathematical equations of gravity hold in all cases with masses, planets, stars, galaxies .... In classical gravitation masses react to the gravitational potential with [Newton's gravitational law,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_law_of_universal_gravitation)  between two bodies

[image: grav]

m1 and m2 are the masses of the bodies and G the gravitational constant.

If there existed only two bodies in a universe *at rest* with each other,  the mathematics would lead to one mass falling on the other inevitably, because no matter how far away, the attraction would be fatal. How do we get planetary systems, galaxies, etc? Because there exist  rotational forces, the way the moon does not fall on the earth. When one goes to the n body case a lot of interplay between gravitational and rotational forces generates the trajectories of planets, comets, satellites ....

The case of a [black hole](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_hole) is different , *when up close to it* for individual two body attraction, because of its great mass, it will attract strongly matter around it. The same is true of heavy stars, *except* the black hole is a special case of [General relativity,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_relativity) where there exists the point of no return, the horizon. Whereas a rocket can release a mass from the earth, the mathematics of GR is such that no rocket can escape a black hole from below the horizon.

Still a black hole and its surrounding masses are an n body classical  gravitational problem when at a distance from it, so it is a matter of the particular distribution of masses/matter around it for how much and how fast it can grow by absorbing everything that cannot escape its attraction. There cannot be a fixed limit, because it depends on the location and the star distributions where the black hole exists.

Black holes exist in the center of galaxies, and the galaxies still exist, because of the n-body gravitational problem, with rotational curves of the stars and planets that are stable against the great attraction of the central black hole. In a sense it is angular momentum conservation between cosmic bodies that saves the day.

Comment: Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

> We know that a black hole draws everything nearby into it but is there
>   a limit to which black holes can consume matter into it?

No upper limit, we know of black holes that span from several times the mass of the sun to several billion times the mass of the sun - so quite a bit of range there!

But on the other side of the spectrum, it appears there is the lower limit around 4 times the mass of the sun. There was some speculation that very small "quantum black holes" could be created in certain cases, but we've found no evidence of them and later understood it is unlikely they would still exist.